# issues running Powershell script on Linux

Tags: linux, powershell, zabbix

Following this guide:https://b-blog.info/en/monitoring-azure-resources-with-zabbix.html

On Windows getting output from script, but when executing on Zabbix (Centos 7) just getting only "data". No SELinux, no Firewall

```
pwsh azure.discovery.sql.databases.ps1 rg 111-222-222244-99
{"data":}
```

Authentication is working because azure.json contains token and it's identical to file on Windows machine

Installed Powerhell 6.0.2 for Linux

Anything missing here ?

Output from Win 10 Lap-top:

```
.\2.ps1 rg 111111
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/9111111/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/mojsql/databases?api-version=2014-04-01
{"data":{
    "{#RGNAME}":  "rg",
    "{#ID}":  "/subscriptions/111111/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/mojsql/databases/mojabaza",
    "{#SERVERNAME}":  "mojsql",
    "{#DATABASENAME}":  "mojabaza"
```

Zabbix is run on as Hyper-V VM hosted on Windows Lap-top from which i can get output

Comment: "I got a script from a blog and it doesn't work" is way too broad; Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ . The output comes from `$result | convertto-json` so there is nothing in `$result`. That says that it's not finding any SQL databases other than `'master'` to display, or that it's not finding any SQL servers, or that it's not logging into Azure. (Is SELinux allowing `pwsh` to make internet connections? Is your hardware firewall?) Is the token file it makes present/absent on one OS vs the other?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, just updated question

Comment: The point is only you have that environment, so debugging is up to you. There are a lot commented out write-host commands you could use to see differences to your Lap-top version.

Comment: The second parameter is `$subscription_id` - in the one which works you use `111111` and in the one which doesn't work you use `111-222-222244-99` - is that just you changing it to obscure the real one for StackOverflow posting? I'm hard pressed to see it failing to make web requests, because the `-ErrorAction Stop` should throw up some very visible errors if it couldn't connect, or if it got login denied messages. Insert a new line after line 56 saying `write-host "servers: $sql_servers"` and another after 66, saying `write-host "databases: $sql_databases"` and see if it finds any, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

finally found what was issue:

on my lap-top i had to substitute `.content.properties` with `Value` (original script didn't yield any results-i first tested it on windows) and just copied it to Linux.

Then just reverted back (replaced `Value` with `.content.properties`) and it started working